# My internet fingerprint

Tags: fingerprint

Please, Do you know any way to delete absolutely all my info from the web? Like, all the info in social media, public places, forums, photoblog. I was using those places without control or worries about privacy. Since my computer got infected with virus, I am more concern with security issues and privacy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Internet doesn't work that way; no single entity has complete control over it. You will need to separately contact each and every website that you've ever used to request that they remove your data. Not all of them will comply.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to remove everything from the entire internet because servers have copies of other servers, and many places (without legal action placed against them for a real reason) will not remove things even if you ask. If you are lucky, contact individual sites where you have information records and ask or check their policies-- but all are of course independent of each other and different in what they allow.

Reputation.com claims to have a large effect, but I cannot be sure of their (and therefore your) results at all.

There is also the possibility of legality of public records. If you have public information for any work you have done or anything in public [sport, events, exhibits...] it is very possibly posted.

There are also the possibility of legal records. If you are in the United States for example, and people know which state you are in, and you get so much as a traffic ticket, it is often live on a public access site. People may have to know more information to find it, but it can often be found for free and a little research.

Comment: Too bad that we cannot erase the info from all those sites more easily. Really, I do not care if my info stay on the servers, I am happy for that. For me deleting my public info, contacting people separately would like a full time job. I would try to start cleaning little by little which ever I need to erase. Thanks Jeff.

Comment: As with anyone who's experienced identity theft (similar process), it is a full time job and basically, if it really means that much to you, you bite the bullet and start the process for what can be changed and deal with the rest. Get offline, move elsewhere and legally change your real life identity is the most severe tactic.

Comment: @Rain sadly you and Fiasco are both right... A full time job and often not worth trying. Changing your identity if your life needs such a drastic change would be the only thing left.

Comment: @Fiasco and Jeff. Well ignorance and ingenuity are a very bad combination. Also I am not so smart like you guys. No idea that we can change identity either. Thanks again.